# Dividing by factors

Tags: javascript, math

I have an integer X and a list of all the factors of X. I want to output the ratio between X and a factor, and for each time set X to that ratio. I want this algorithm to continue till the ratio is bigger than or equal to 1.

For example: X = 36.

All factors (but 1 and 36): 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, 18,

Algorithm: 36 / 2 = 18 --> 18 / 3 = 6 --> 6 / 4 = 1.5 --> 1.5 / 6 < 1 --> Stop

Output: [18, 6, 1.5]. Question:

How do I get this output?

What i have written:

```
var arr = [];

  for (var i = 2; i < X; i++) {
    if (X % i == 0) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
  }

  var temp = [];

  var index = 0;
  while (X / arr[index] >= 1) {
    index += 1;
    X = X / arr[index];
    temp.push(X / arr[index]);
  }
```

Comment: i don't get it - your first loop does find all factors. What do you want afterwards? - https://jsfiddle.net/mLpmhmdx/

Comment: I guess the `temp.push` line should go before the `X=X/` line. Also, try to find better var names (e.g. arr => factors, temp => results)

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the first value before you go into the while loop an check the asssigned `x`. If the value passes the condition, you could push that value to the result array and increment the index and calculate a new value.

```js
function fn(x) {
    var array = [],               // declare all variable on top
        i,
        result = [];

    for (var i = 2; i < x; i++) {
        if (x % i == 0) {
            array.push(i);
        }
    }
    i = 0;                        // prepare index for looping
    x /= array[i];                // take a first possible value
    while (x >= 1) {              // check value
        result.push(x);           // push value
        i++;                      // increment index
        x /= array[i];            // take the next value for checking
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(fn(36))
```

A bit shorter with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
function fn(x) {
    var array = [],               // declare all variable on top
        i,
        result = [];

    for (var i = 2; i < x; i++) {
        if (x % i == 0) {
            array.push(i);
        }
    }
    array.every(v => (x /= v) >= 1 && result.push(x));
    return result;
}

console.log(fn(36))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [];
  var X = 36
  for (var i = 2; i < X; i++) {
    if (X % i == 0) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
  }
  
  var temp = arr.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
      if(!(X/item < 1)){
          acc.push(X/item)
          X = X/item;
      }
      return acc;
  }, [])
  
  console.log(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit confuse. Is this what you want?

Basically, I update the factor after each iteration (if >= 1) and store into an array the output.

```js
// Generate a range of integers (starting at 2, and we should not including the input)
// get only values divisible by the input (filter)
const generateRange = (input) => {
  return Array.from({length: (input - 2)}, (v, k) => k + 2).filter(i => {
    return input % i === 0;
  })
}

const divideFactors = (input) => {
  const list = generateRange(input) // filtered range
  let output = [] 
  let factor = input 
  
  for (const item of list) {
    let ratio = factor / item

    if (ratio < 1) { //if ratio < 1, break the loop
      break;
    }     
    
    output.push(ratio) // update output array with new ratio
    factor = ratio; // update factor variable with current ratio
  }

  return output
}

console.log(divideFactors(36))
```

**More info:**

**Array.from:**  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

**For of:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of